# how to clear data in a jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two JTables in a JScrollPane (table1 and Table2) when I select any row in table1 some information related to that row is displayed in table 2. My issue is if I select one row and then select another row the data related to 2nd row is being appended in table 2 instead I want table 2 to show only 2nd row's data when I select 2nd row and not both row 1 and row 2 data. Can anyone please help.

Comment: post some code, we don't like to read text is easy to get confused..

Comment: Also, this title is very incorrect for what the problem actually is...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: sorry about the title, wanted to post a different question yesterday started typing then I found a solution so didn't post. I guess that title got saved, I haven't checked before posting

Comment: So you have a 2nd table that show related data to the selected row in the 1st table? And this 2nd table would only ever have 1 row? Personally, I wouldn't use a table for this. I'd show this supporting data in separate JComponents (JTextFields, JCheckBoxes, etc.) that are appropriate for the data shown.  Just my 2c.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just reset the table model of your second table before adding in the new data. Here is a simple example of a reset method you could use.

```
void clear() {
  model.setRowCount(0);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I found a solution for the question. I'm doing this table.getDataVectop().removeAllElements(); before adding new data to table. It does the job!

Comment: @codelearner, `I'm doing this table.getDataVectop().removeAllElements();` - that is NOT the way to solve the problem. Then answer given by Rob is the better approach. When you want to make changes to the data you should upated the TableModel. You should not be updating the data structure of the model. +1 for Rob's suggestion.